# API test not good without Postman

Tags: powershell, postman

I was told that testing a web api with pPowershell is not as effective as using Postman. Are they different and do you need both?

Appreciate any input from someone who has used both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, Postman provides various functionality to test the API in a proper manner. Well, Postman can also provide CLI Environment called as Newman-CLI-Runner. Moreover, you can even create an end-to-end automation suite in postman as well. Last but not the least, you can set the API monitors but it requires a pro plan.

Answer (score 0):

postman can sync your setting that your operations. I deem powershell is a subset of postman...

I recommand postman too ~